# HtmlHelper<dynamic> does not contain a definition for CodeEffects

Tags: rule-engine, business-rules, codeeffects

I copy code from project to another project to use it in our project but I face issue in view , I get this error

> 'HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'CodeEffects'
> and no accessible extension method 'CodeEffects' accepting a first
> argument of type 'HtmlHelper' could be found

(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I get this error in  when I write

```
Html.CodeEffects().Styles()
        .Render();
```

And I get this error

The name 'RuleType' does not exist in the current context

```
    Html.CodeEffects().RuleEditor()
            .Id("ruleEditor")
            .Mode(RuleType.Execution)
            .ClientOnly(true)
            .Rule(ViewBag.Rule)
            .Render();
```

Comment: Please make sure you have the same Code Effects references as the demo project has

Comment: I do it by add reference
Install-Package CodeEffects.Rule.Editor.Mvc
Install-Package CodeEffects.Rule.Engine.Standard.Trial

and add scripts and style

Comment: I get this error 
The given ruleset does not contain any rules with type Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null (#106)'